# How to get messages from SQL Server messagePane in .NET application

Tags: .net, sql-server

I want to get messages in case of success or failure. So both conditions should return me something from message pane.

This is the code I am trying to use, but this never call the `conn_InfoMessage`. It always skips that.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sp.StoredProcedureName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                conn.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(conn_InfoMessage); 
                pnlResults.Visible = true;
                grdResults.DataSource = dr;
                grdResults.DataBind();
            }
        }


    lblInfo.Text = myMsg;

        pnlInfo.CssClass = "ui-state-active";
    }
    conn.Close();
}

static void conn_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) 
{
    myMsg +=  "/n" + e.Message ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By the time you can call dr.HasRows it is too late.  You need to hook up the event handler at an earlier time.. say, right before you open the connection.

Comment: I Added this code as mentioned but still does not call event handler:  conn.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(conn_InfoMessage);
                    conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
                    conn.Open();

Comment: how do you know its not called?  Are you setting a breakpoint, or is nothing showing up on the label?

Comment: yeap using breakpoint, during error or warning , I can see it calling . but when there is no error or it is successful , it just bypass the code and go to next line. I want it to work when stored executed successfully

Comment: is there any way , i can force it to execute no mater what ?

Comment: your question is unclear.  you say it IS firing correctly.. just not when you would like it to.. so.. when would you like it to?

Comment: You should have called dr. HasRows earlier... now it's too late... poor sob... :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're enabling that event **before** you open the connection or make use of it in any other way:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(conn_InfoMessage);
    conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
    conn.Open();

    // rest of code follows...
```

Comment: I added the code in start as said..but still not calling the event handler..not sure what I am missing

Comment: Your query may not be raising any of those events in that case.

Comment: this is executing stored proc. i can see messages in message pane from sqlserver management studio when I execute it .

Comment: I have a doubt does this event get called even when no warning or failure. I mean when the stored proc is executed successfully..does this event get called ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `SqlInfoMessageEventHandler` delegate before you execute the command. I'd move it to the next line after the `Conn.Open` method call.